# Wordpress CSS Assistance with Column col-md-8 and Padding

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, wordpress

Unfortunately I won't be able to describe my issue without a visit to my site. DadGab.com.

I have a 'featured slider' col-md-8 with a sidebar to the right. It appears there is some padding or spacing set somewhere and I am unable to find it. I've checked all theme files, style.php. All I am trying to do is move the sidebar on the right side to the top of the page. The empty space did used to be a col-md-4 container which the coding has since been removed.

If I remove the featured slider code from the main page, the 'latest' posts as well as the menu do move to the top of the screen without the padding issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current scenario is following

```
<div class="col-md-8">
    featured slider
</div>

<div class="col-md-8">
    content
</div>

<div class="col-md-4">
    sidebar
</div>
```

Change it to following

```
<div class="col-md-8">
    featured slider
    content
</div>

<div class="col-md-4">
    sidebar
</div>
```

Please let me know if issue is still there :)

Answer (score 1):

you have the following structure

```
<div class="col-md-8"></div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="col-md-8"></div>
<div class="col-md-4"></div>
```

if i understand you corectly you should have

```
<div class="col-md-8"></div>
<div class="col-md-4"></div>
```

so join the code from both .col-md-8 containers, remove the div with class "clear" and it should be OK. This is all done in template homepage.php

Answer (score 1):

You have some problems in your layout logic. You need to think about the way columns and rows work.

You should have a left column (`col-md-8`) and a sidebar column (`col-md-4`) and they should be adjacent. The left column should contain ALL of the left content.

Here's what you have:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <!-- featured -->
  </div>

  <div class="clear"><!-- SEPARATION --></div>

  <div class="col-md-8">
    <!-- REAST OF LEFT COLUMN -->
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
     <!--
       SIDEBAR
       You want this next to the left column.
       But it's not adjacent!
     -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's what you want

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <!-- FEATURED -->
    <!-- REST OF LEFT COLUMN -->
  </div> 
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <!-- RIGHT SIDEBAR -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

After your div "col-md-8" is coming a clearfix. Just creat a "col-md-4" after "col-md-8".
I already tested here, just do it.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the tags

```
<div class="container"><div class="row">
```

rearrange the order, from:

```
<div class="col-md-8"> ... </div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="col-md-8"> ... </div>
<div class="col-md-4"> ... </div>
```

to:

```
<div class="col-md-8"> ... </div>
<div class="col-md-4"> ... </div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="col-md-8"> ... </div>
```

In addition, consider if you really want to keep the div that clears out your floats:

```
<div class="clear"></div>
```

If not, comment it out, like so:

```
<!-- <div class="clear"></div> -->
```

This indeed moves up your sidebar to the position you want. However, I suspect you will want the last div (of class col-md-8) to be positioned higher. If so, it sounds as if you will need to create two columns *inside* the row (the div of class row).